# How to declare the parameter in a JS function to be only string data type?

Tags: javascript, string, parameters, functional-programming

I have a beginner's exercise in JavaScript and the current code looks like this:

```
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
    var message = "%c" + txt;
    var style = `color: ${color};`
    style += `background: ${background};`
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
    console.log(message, style);
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
    if (reason == 'birthday') {
        console.log(`%cHappy Birthday`, fontStyle);
    } else if (reason == "champions") {
        console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
    } else {
        console.log(message, style); 
    }
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions
consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday');


// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason) {
    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);  
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e', 'fae8e0', '30px', 'You made it', 'champions');
```

The second function (task 2) should accept a **single parameter, reason**, which should be of **string data type.**
If I run the code in VSC, it works. However, in the grading system I get the following:

> Failed Test 2: Not logging celebrateStyler() variables

> Failed Test 3: Not calling consoleStyler() and celebrateStyler()

I tried different options to declare the parameter as a string (using typeof mostly), but unfortunately I get the same result.

Can you maybe take a look and give me some advice on how to approach the situation using only JS?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: the `celebrateStyler` accepts only single parameter, however in task 3 you are executing that function with 4 parameters.

Comment: I think this should satisfy;
`if(typeof reason !== 'string') {
//return some error
}
// otherwise run the function`

Answer (score 4):

complete solution got 100/100

```
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
function consoleStyler(color,background ,fontSize,txt) {
    var message = "%c" + txt;
    var style = `color: ${color};`
    style += `background: ${background};`
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
    console.log(message, style);
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {

    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
    if ( reason == "birthday")
    {
     console.log(`%cHappy birthday`, fontStyle);
    }
    else if (reason == "champions") {
        console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
    }
    else {
        console.log(reason,fontStyle);
    }
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions
consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday');


// // Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt ,reason) {
consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
celebrateStyler(reason);
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate

styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e','fae8e0','30px','You made it!','champions');

enter code here

//
```

Answer (score 1):

## Parameter types

Javascript is a weakly typed language, which, in you case means that you cannot enforce a certain type to be the type of a parameter.

## Understanding the errors

You get a text that contains "Failed Test : ".

So, the very interesting part is the test name, which hints for the objective.

## Not logging celebrateStyler() variables

The expectation in the title of this section shows that there is a test scenario which expects your code to avoid logging the variables. Let's see the function:

```
// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
    if (reason == 'birthday') {
        console.log(`%cHappy Birthday`, fontStyle);
    } else if (reason == "champions") {
        console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
    } else {
        console.log(message, style); 
    }
}
```

This function will perform a call on `console.log` whatever `reason` is. Yet, you should not do this logging as per the specification if `reason` is not a string. So, you need to do some type checking and if the parameter is a string, only then perform your logic. I'm doing a sample implementation in the snippet below, which you can of course adjust to your needs:

```js
// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    if (typeof reason === "string") {
        var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
        if (reason == 'birthday') {
            console.log(`%cHappy Birthday`, fontStyle);
        } else if (reason == "champions") {
            console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
        } else {
            console.log(reason, fontStyle); 
        }
    } else {
        //If you want to do something with a nonstring reason, this is the right place to do it
    }
}

celebrateStyler('birthday'); //Happy Birthday
celebrateStyler('champions'); //Congrats on the title!
celebrateStyler('Welcome Back!'); //Welcome Back
celebrateStyler(42); //No logging, because it's not a string
```

Note that I have changed the `connsole.log` in your last `else` block to use the same style. If you dislike this, you can use your own message and style, of course.

## Not calling consoleStyler() and celebrateStyler()

This is telling you that `styleAndCelebrate` should not call the functions mentioned above. As a result, you need to check for the type of `reason` and if it's not a string, then don't call the methods:

```
// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason) {
    if (typeof reason === "string") {
        consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);  
        celebrateStyler(reason);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the complete solution here.

```
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
function consoleStyler(color,background,fontSize,txt) {
    message = "%c" + txt
    style = `color: ${color};`
    style += `background: ${background};`
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
    console.log(message,style)
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
 fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
 if (reason == "birthday") {
    console.log(`%cHappy birthday`, fontStyle);
} else if (reason == "champions") {
    console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
} else {
    console.log(message, style);
}
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions
consoleStyler('#1d5c63','#ede6db','40px','congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday');

// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate() {
    consoleStyler('ef7c8e','fae8e0', '30px', 'You made it!');  
    celebrateStyler('birthday');
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate
styleAndCelebrate();
```

Hopefully, this will work as expected! Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
    var message = "%c" + txt;
    var style = `color: ${color};`;
    style += `background: ${background};`;
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`;

    console.log(message, style);
    
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
    if (reason == "birthday") {
        console.log(`%cHappy birthday`, fontStyle);
    }
    else if (reason == "champions") {
        console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);

    }
    else {
        console.log(reason, fontStyle);
    }
    
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions
consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday');
                                    // Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt,reason) {
    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);  
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e', 'fae8e0', '30px', 'You made it!', 'champions');`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just Copy and paste the console message from the instruction and your all test will simply pass! :)

```
    // Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
    var message;
    var style;
function consoleStyler(color,background,fontSize,txt) {
    message = "%c" + txt;
    style = `color: ${color};`
    style += `background: ${background};`
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
    console.log(message,style);
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
        if (reason == "birthday") {
            console.log(`%cHappy birthday`, fontStyle);
        }
        else if (reason == "champions") {
            console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
        }
        else {
            console.log(message,style);
        }
    
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions
    consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!');
       celebrateStyler('birthday')
// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason)
{
    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e','fae8e0','30px','You made it!','champions')
```

```js
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator
var message;
var style;
function consoleStyler(color,background,fontSize,txt) {
    message = "%c" + txt;
    style = `color: ${color};`
    style += `background: ${background};`
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
    console.log(message,style);
}

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
    
        if (reason == "birthday") {
            console.log(`%cHappy birthday`, fontStyle);
        }
        else if (reason == "champions") {
            console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
        }
        else {
            console.log(message,style);
        }
    
}

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions
consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday')

// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason)
{

    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}
// Call styleAndCelebrate
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e','fae8e0','30px','You made it!','champions')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem everyone facing is that the `massage` and the `style` variable must be defined at the scope of the code before the first function most of us were defining these variables at the `consoleStyler` function.

The problem is we call them on `console.log` at the `celebrateStyler` function in the `else` statement.